# Cannot edit the form in this jquery code lines when display on browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Note that this isnt my code, so i dont understand that much. So,this the html that used to trigger the divedit-member, as you can see below

```
<div class="right-sidebar divedit-member">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="member-form"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then this is script that at i use to edit the form of to edit MEMBER, just wanted to change the value of input tag name=s_year to other such as (1st, 2nd,3rd) but then cant managed to do so. when im edited the option tag it still display this form, which i dont want..

```
$('.add_student').click(function()
{   
    $('.divedit-member').toggle(effect, options, duration);

    var form = '<form class="frm_add_student">\
                    <br/><br/><h4 class=""></h4>\
                    <hr>\
                    <div class="form-group">\
                        <label>School ID Number</label>\
                        <input type="number" name="sid_number" class="form-control" required autocomplete="off">\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="form-group">\
                        <label>First Name</label>\
                        <input type="text" name="s_fname" class="form-control text-capitalize" required autocomplete="off">\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="form-group">\
                        <label>Last Name</label>\
                        <input type="text" name="s_lname" class="form-control text-capitalize" required autocomplete="off">\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="form-group">\
                        <label>Gender</label>\
                        <select name="s_gender" class="form-control" required>\
                            <option disabled selected>Your gender</option>\
                            <option>Male</option>\
                            <option>Female</option>\
                        </select>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="form-group">\
                        <label>Contact Number</label>\
                        <input type="tel" name="s_contact" class="form-control" required autocomplete="off">\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="form-group">\
                        <label>Department</label>\
                        <select name="s_department" class="form-control" required>\
                            <option disabled selected>Select department</option>\
                            <option>FSKM</option>\
                        </select>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="form-group hide">\
                        <label>Major</label>\
                        <input type="text" name="s_major" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="form-group">\
                        <div class="row">\
                            <div class="col-md-6">\
                                <label>Year</label>\
                                <select name="s_year" class="form-control" required>\
                                    <option selected disabled>Select year</option>\
                                    <option>1</option>\
                                    <option>2</option>\
                                    <option>3</option>\
                                    <option>4</option>\
                                    <option>5</option>\
                                </select>\
                            </div>\
                            <div class="col-md-6">\
                                <label>Section</label>\
                                <input type="text" name="s_section" class="form-control text-capitalize" required autocomplete="off">\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="form-group">\
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn_faculty" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add</button>\
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn_frm_add" type="reset"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i> Cancel</button>\
                    </div>\
                </form>';

        $('.member-form').html(form);
        $('.btn_frm_add').click(function(e){
            $('.divedit-member').toggle(effect, options, duration);
        });

        $('.frm_add_student').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var frmdata = $(this).serialize()+'&key=add_newstudent';

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../class/add/add",
                data: frmdata
            })
            .done(function(data){
                // console.log(data);
                if(data == 1){
                    toastr.success('Student successfully added.');
                    $('.btn_frm_add').click();
                    table_member.ajax.reload(null,false);

                }else if(data == 2){
                    toastr.warning('Student already exist.');
                }else{
                    toastr.error('Failed to add.');
                }
            });

        });

});
```

If im wrong somewhere,please do help me.

Comment: <option value='1'>1st</option>\

Comment: ty for replying but I know that. Maybe u dont understand me. The problem is when I change, it doesn't display just like i wanted to be.

Comment: What exactly your output requirements

Comment: yes i want to change to this <option value='1'>1st</option>\ but it doesnt work inside browser when i change the anything from the <form>

Comment: Do you want to select the option as student changes? If yes then use selected inside your string at desired option that may help you please do let me know if this is requirement I will post the resolution accordingly